# to_number substring remove zero at lefthands?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this string

abcd-0490-abcd

I am getting the number part using `substr('abcd-0490-abcd',5,4)` but the problem is that I want to increment that number by one so I add the to_number like that

```
 to_number(substr('abcd-0490-abcd', 5,4 ))
```

which will remove the zero number at the left hand that's coz an error to my script so its not catching correct data i want

anyway to avoid this

```
create or replace procedure pro
(yy in varchar2 default '[0-9]{2}',mm in varchar2 default '[0-9]{2}') as pattern varchar2(80);
  cursor cur (pattern varchar2) is

    with t as
    (
      select 
        substr(column1, 5,4 ) as seq,
        substr(column1, 10, 2) as yy,
        substr(column1, 13, 2) as mm,
        substr(column1, 16, 2) as dd
      from test1
      where regexp_like(column1, pattern)
    ),
    r (yy, mm, dd, seq, max_seq) as (
      select yy, mm, dd, min(seq), max(seq)
      from t
      group by yy, mm, dd
      union all
      select yy, mm, dd, seq + 1, max_seq
      from r
      where seq + 1 <= max_seq
    )
    select yy, mm, dd, seq as missing_seq
    from r
    where not exists (
      select 1 from t
      where t.yy = r.yy
      and t.mm = r.mm
      and t.dd = r.dd
      and t.seq = r.seq
    )
    order by yy, mm, dd, seq;
begin          
     pattern := 'Cabcd[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}'|| yy ||'[_][0-9]{2}' || mm || '[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][T]["2"]';      

  for rec in cur(pattern) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.missing_seq);
  end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('Done');

end pro;
/
```

Comment: But if you want it was a number, why are you concerned with having a leading 0 ?

Comment: post my code to understand how to help me

Comment: You seem to have changed the regex pattern again, and mangled the yy/mm/dd matching from the earlier question.

Answer (score 4):

Use LPAD function:http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions095.htm#SQLRF00663

```
select lpad( to_number(substr('abcd-0490-abcd', 6,4 )) + 1 , 4, '0')
from dual;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25730

Answer (score 1):

The default number-to-character conversion does not produce leading zeros.

Do an explicit `TO_CHAR` to define your format:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(490, 'FM0000') FROM dual;

0490
```

**Edit:** This is an example with your query.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( 'abcd-0490-abcd', 6, 4 ) ) + 1, 'FM0000' )
FROM dual;

0491
```

Comment: i will not be able to increment it after that coz its not treated as number

Comment: You should increment it before, and convert it like this **afterwards**.

Comment: I cant do it post my code to understand how to help me

Comment: i cant increment it b4

Comment: Why not? Did you see my update? It does the increment and converts afterwards.

Comment: its right but the increment should be next steps not  after supstr look at my code at first post

Comment: Use `select yy, mm, dd, TO_CHAR(seq, 'FM0000') as missing_seq` and you should be fine.

Comment: code works fine without any error but the result still incorrect... here is what I am trying to do http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/678b6/9/0 I had delete a record from table and does not print me that this number is missing ?

Comment: I doubt that this is related to your original question, which would be confusing for other readers. Consider asking another question where you analyze and describe your new problem..

Answer (score 0):

better u try " rownum " for increment

SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( 'abcd-0490-abcd', 6, 4 ) ) +rownum, 'FM0000' )
FROM dual;

use table dual instead of any other table in ur database.

SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( 'abcd-0490-abcd', 6, 4 ) ) +rownum, 'FM0000' )
FROM 'your_tablename';

Comment: thats mean I have to change the whole procedure... am I right !?

Comment: ummmm is the 'FM0000' part is the format of number ?? or what do u mean with it

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( 'abcd-0998-abcd', 6, 4 ) ) +rownum, 'FM0000' ) FROM 'your_tablename';

Comment: here is sample data my friend i just wanna check that there is no missing number in sequence part http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/678b6/9/0

Comment: i have tried to delete a record from this table and is not giving me that this record is missing